# passing checkbox values from form to a php page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a form with a form where the checkbox is created for every record that is generated (from random search) like :

```
name    value   id .... 
abc      24      x145       []checkbox
xyz      19      b234       []checkbox
...
```

Since the records are dynamically generated, I have a single line in the form which says

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)"></input>
```

Therefore a checkbox is added for each line (record). How can I pass on the values of the checkbox from this form to another form for post processing? I tried the usual `$_POST['cb']`, but had no luck with that.

Comment: Is `$_POST['cb']` undefined? It shoud contain an array. try using a debugger/var_dump to see what's inside??

Comment: Maybe because your checkbox doesnt have any value?

Comment: it will be in array. print_r($_POST) to what is in $_POST['cb']

Comment: When i print out contents of $_POST, it returns an empty array (which should not be the case). I tried another option of putting default value =0 too, no luck with that either.

Comment: Please provide the complete HTML code for the form and fields. Does the form tag enclose the checkbox fields correctly?

Answer (score 0):

HTML checkboxes does not work like `$_POST["cb"][0]==true`
If they are checked, the form will be submit with their value, so `$_POST["cb"][0]` will contain null as you dont have any value specified or maybe they are not even submitted as they have no value.

You will need to use something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="checked" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)"></input>
```

Comment: I indeed did check with value="checked" and then tried accessing them using    for($_POST["cb"] as $key=>$value) { if(isset($value) ... }  No luck with that either.

Comment: then you will need to post example of your form or output of `var_export($_POST)`